# Quick PHP: declaring multiple elements

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I just had a quick question on how to declare a function properly, it's currently returning 0! This works:

```
    function __construct($details, $email_admin){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->subject = 'New Subscriber To Yourmessage Mailing List'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['name'];


    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
}
```

But I want to display name and email in the message like this "John Doe - johndoe@johnnyD.com"

This is what I have so far but i must not be declaring properly, what would be the correct definition of multiple elements?

```
    function __construct($details, $email_admin){

    $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
    $this->email = trim($details['email']);
    $this->subject = 'New Subscriber To Yourmessage Mailing List'; // Subject 
    $this->message = stripslashes($details['name'] + ' - ' + $details['email']);


    $this->email_admin = $email_admin;

    $this->response_status = 1;
    $this->response_html = '';
}
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php.

Comment: A constructor will only return an instance of the class it is in. What is your question?

Comment: Btw, you have a potential typo in `stripslashes($details['name'];` which should read as `stripslashes($details['name']);` missing closing `)`

Comment: As I said im new to PHP and the question is pretty clear which is why its being answered, there is no need to negative the question because its legit and its not off topic either. Thanks Fred I ill update with missing  ")"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP you concatenate strings using the dot '.', not the plus '+' like in Java.

Probably you get a runtime error in this line

```
$this->message = stripslashes($details['name'] + ' - ' + $details['email']);
```

Instead you should

```
$this->message = stripslashes($details['name'] . ' - ' . $details['email']);
```

Comment: Yes thank you!!! this worked, I knew it was something minor. And thanks for just answering instead of being patronising.